# How to change what program Apple ProDOS 'starts' when booting

Tags: apple-ii, boot, apple-dos

I finally have my Apple //e booting from my SCSI2SD but I'm missing something regarding how ProDOS knows what program to start when it boots.

As I understand it, ProDOS will look for the first `.SYSTEM` file and launch that, which seems simple enough.

But what if you want to change a bad decision you made months ago?  In my case, I was working from the newly released ProDOS 2.4.2 and copied over the files `PRODOS` and `BASIC.SYSTEM` (and sure enough, I wind up at the basic prompt when I boot).

But the floppy disk I was working from seems to have `QUIT.SYSTEM` as the first system file, and *that* disk boots into `BITSY.BOOT`, so I have to suppose that `QUIT.SYSTEM` is redirecting the boot loader somehow.

If I wanted to change my existing ProDOS disk to stop loading into `BASIC.SYSTEM` and instead load into `BITSY.BOOT`, how would I move the `QUIT.SYSTEM` to appear *before* the existing `BASIC.SYSTEM`?

How does a user manipulate the order of the files to change which `.SYSTEM` file you want to currently use?

I would be astounded if the answer is to "delete everything and add files in the correct order". I feel like I am missing something fundamental, but snooping around the web hasn't exactly been very informative.

Would someone kindly kick-start my brain please?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that typical ProDOS disks hold more than one .SYSTEM program - They don't. If you want another one, put it on a separate disk or delete the old, then create the new one. Those old 8-bit systems were way less sophisticated than you might assume.

Comment: @tofro: a valid point for 140KB floppies, but on the Apple IIgs, 800KB floppies were common. So what constitutes a "typical" ProDOS disk is subject to context.

Comment: @fadden Well, even on 800k (which includes the IIC+, my main machine to do apple II nowadays) one had different floppies for different environments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorting the root directory to put the desired `.SYSTEM` program first will fix the issue.

You can sort a directory on a ProDOS disk with the [ProSel-8 disk utilities](http://www.brutaldeluxe.fr/documentation/prosel/index.html) or [Copy II+](https://prodos8.com/copy-ii-plus/).  You can also just format a new disk, and copy all of the files to it in the desired order.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer mostly because all proposed solutions dance around the same concept; which is to have a single SYSTEM file in the root directory or manually sort the files to move the preferred SYSTEM file to the top using a third-party tool.  But I'm not going to do either of these things, because the RIFA capacitor in my power supply just let the magic smoke out, _sigh_.

Comment: @Geo... in reality, fadden's suggestion of using those tools to re-arrange the directory IS what we did back in the day. The ProDOS binary only searches for a .SYSTEM suffix.

Comment: Yea, it makes sense - I was a DOS3.3 guy, and never really embraced ProDOS (as I moved to focus more on my C64 at home, and later my Amiga 1000).  Sometimes a feature or 'way of doing things' seems so obvious it's hard to believe it wasn't included back then.  :-P

Answer (score 4):

> I would be astounded if the answer is to "delete everything and add files in the correct order"

Jup, that's 'a' solution :))

ProDOS only expects a single SYSTEM to exist on the boot volume. It will always start the first it finds in the volume directory.

---

### Details:

#### Boot Process

Booting an Apple II is a straightforward process:

- After basic initialisation the monitor looks for a bootable card
- If found it jumps to that card's PROM
- For a DISK II (compatible) card the boot sector gets loaded to $800
- The boot sector loads its remaining code from the following sector.
- For PRODOS that code then looks for a file named PRODOS
- PRODOS is loaded to $2000 and executed
- PRODOS checks for memory size and moves itself up to top of memory
- Now PRODOS searches the volume directory of the boot volume for the first file with type $FF and a name ending in ".SYSTEM"
- If found that file gets loaded to $2000 and executed.

#### What To Do:

Solution A: **Have only one .SYSTEM file in a boot volumes directory**

This can be done in several ways:

- Have different disks for different purposes
- Rename all unused SYSTEMs to something else - like 'NONSYS'

  To change, rename the actual SYSTEM to NONSYS and the desired one to SYSTEM before rebooting
- Have them in subdirectories and create a fake BOOT.SYSTEM which points to one of them

  To change, fiddle with the linking.

Solution B: **Create a boot manager**

That is, write a program, let's call it GRUB.SYSTEM, which will, when loaded, look in some configuration file for what SYSTEM to be loaded - or offer a menu of such - and load whatever is selected using an MLI call. GRUB.SYSTEM must be the first - or better the only - SYSTEM file on that volume.

Of course that could be made indefinitely complex ... err I mean comfortable :))

Comment: I wonder how hard it would be for a .SYSTEM file to patch one of the bytes in the word ".SYSTEM" used to find a matching file (e.g. changing it to ".SYSTE2"), and then exit in a manner that would cause the boot code to search for a file called ".SYSTE2" without having to modify anything on disk?

Comment: @supercat The first part isn't hard at all, as the DOS is already present and all function needed, like searching for a file, can be used via MLI.

Comment: @supercat: re "without having to modify anything on disk", wouldn't you have to modify the preferred file on disk to have this new extension? Or have I misunderstood the proposal?

Comment: @paxdiablo: The idea would be that the patch would happen in the copy of the loader in RAM.

Comment: Raffzahn, I just wanted to say thanks for your answer - I'm taking the lazy way out and will simply rework my root directory to contain a single SYSTEM file.  Alternate files can go into subdirectories, and can be easily selected from the 'bitsy bye' menu.  - That's a fun idea about the GRUB.SYSTEM tho. It might be worth revisiting at some point down the road when my backlog of "other interesting stuff to work on" starts running low. :-)

Comment: There's a another way, using the reboot MLI command. I'ts a strange beast with an interactive component, which I remember about using path names in some way, but I do not remember the details and had no time to look up the data so far.

Comment: @Raffzahn: there's no "reboot" command; you may be thinking of QUIT ($65), which copies the quit handler from $D100 to $1000 and executes it. The default QUIT handler asks for the next thing to run. See also section 5.1.5: https://prodos8.com/docs/techref/writing-a-prodos-system-program/

Comment: @fadden that's the function I had in mind, especially due it asking for the follow up to run - which IIRC may include a path. So one could select a directory to start from.